# Bitwise AND and modulo in a for loop produce unexpected results

Tags: python

```
for i in range(10):
    if i&3 == 0 or i%5 == 0:
        print(i)
```

Guess what the outputs are?

0
4
5
8

4 and 8 are not supposed to be the output. Why does this happen?

Comment: `4&3` equals `0`.  Did you mean `i%3`?

Comment: You miss ampersand & and percent % sings in first condition

Comment: OMG thank you very much. I miss that.

Comment: Why do you say 4 shouldn't be in the output?  4 and 3 have no one-bits in common -- 4 is `100` and 3 is `011`, therefore `4 & 3` is 0.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [1]: bin(3)
Out[1]: '0b11'

In [2]: bin(5)
Out[2]: '0b101'

In [3]: for i in range(10):
...:     print i, bin(i), i&3, bin(i&3), i&5, bin(i&5)
...:   
0 0b0 0 0b0 0 0b0
1 0b1 1 0b1 1 0b1
2 0b10 2 0b10 0 0b0
3 0b11 3 0b11 1 0b1
4 0b100 0 0b0 4 0b100
5 0b101 1 0b1 5 0b101
6 0b110 2 0b10 4 0b100
7 0b111 3 0b11 5 0b101
8 0b1000 0 0b0 0 0b0
9 0b1001 1 0b1 1 0b1
```

the reason those numbers are showing up is because either the last two bits are off '00' (i&3), or the last three bits are either '000' or '010'

Comment: I intended to use % instead of &. Now I am going to learn what does & means. Thank you.

Comment: your welcome.   & is a bit 'and' operation.